# Huge white-space in latex template (springer journal)

Tags: templates

I'm writing a paper for a Springer journal, so I downloaded Springer journal template from [Springer Manuscript](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX.zip) and after I compiled it, there is a huge white-space on the right.

Anyone know how I can solve that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The template presumably is created to Springer's specifications, so why would you want to change that? The journal decides the layout, not you.

Comment: This space might be reserved for marginal notes. Load package `showframe` to better understand the layout of the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I expect that the dimensions of the text body are chosen on purpose. Filling a complete A4 (or letter) paper would either require

- very long lines ⇒ poor readability; or
- quite large margins ⇒ ineffective high paper costs).

Therefore I assume that the one-column layout is intended for a final paper size that is smaller than A4 (or letter). And I expect that the large margins on the right and the bottom are automatically removed by the journal.

If you want to review a more symmetrical page layout, then the large margins can be reduced to the amount of their counterparts. The following code can be put at the beginning of the file (e.g. `template.tex`). Before submitting, I would remove it. Package `geometry` does not change the layout, if option `pass` is given. But the package tells the page dimensions to the output driver
(`\pdfpagewidth`/`\pdfpageheight` for pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX; `\special{papersize=...}` for dvips, ...).

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \paperwidth=\dimexpr
    1in + \oddsidemargin
    + \textwidth
    % + \marginparsep + \marginparwidth
    + 1in + \oddsidemargin
  \relax
  \paperheight=\dimexpr
    1in + \topmargin
    + \headheight + \headsep
    + \textheight
    % + \footskip
    + 1in + \topmargin
  \relax
  \usepackage[pass]{geometry}\relax
}
```

> [image: Result for page 1]

The final paper size is now about 169.3 mm × 247.4 mm.

Or the original document can be included in a print document via `pdfpages`. Options `trim` control the removed margins. Also the page can be scaled to the output page size A4:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% \extratrim is removed from the margins at each side
\newlength{\extratrim}
\setlength{\extratrim}{10mm}

\newcommand*{\trimexpr}[1]{\dimexpr(#1)+\extratrim\relax}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[
    pages=-,
    trim=\trimexpr{0mm} \trimexpr{49.6mm} \trimexpr{40.7mm} \trimexpr{0mm},
  ]{template.pdf}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]